# Retrieving latitude and longitude from Firebase database and show markers on the map in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a route planner app in Android Studio using OpenStreetMap for the map and Firebase database which has "category", "latitude", and "longitude" I want to be able to retrieve this information and show the locations on my mapview
This is the code I am using in my MainActivity where my mapview is:

```
// Retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("locations");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<VanCameraLocations> locationList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String category = snapshot.child("category").getValue(String.class);
            double latitude = snapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            double longitude = snapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            VanCameraLocations location = new VanCameraLocations(category, latitude, longitude);
            locationList.add(location);
        }
        // Display markers on mapview
        Drawable markerIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_icon);
        for (VanCameraLocations location : locationList) {
            Marker marker = new Marker(mapView);
            marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            marker.setTitle(location.getCategory());
            marker.setIcon(markerIcon);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(marker);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how to add the JSON file to this question but here is what one location I have in my firebase look like

```
{
  "locations": {
    "location1": {
      "Category": "Speed Van",
      "latitude": 52.519345,
      "longitude": -6.610428
    }
```

I'm not sure how this doesn't work can someone help me please

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: The code looks fine to me at first glance, so likely the problem is elsewhere. I recommend debugging the code locally, and telling us the result. So set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line. With this, what is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?